# Slowness and instability after some minutes of html videos

Tags: flash, intel-graphics, html

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and after a few minutes watching Flash streaming videos the OS is slow and unstable. In any browser. I have a Dell Latitude E6400 laptop with Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9400, 2.53GHz, 2GB of RAM and graphics card Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) processor.

Any thoughts on what could it be?

Comment: CPU throttling due to excessive heat springs to mind...

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded flashplugin-installer? If not, try this,

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Hope this helps!